# Enabling 'Minimize' button to an existing program

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I am playing a game which I sometimes use to modify using Cheat Engine / IDA for educational purposes.

Now, I am trying to understand of how I can add the Minimize button to the program itself, since it only has the X button.

[image]

and I want it to be as:

[image]

I'd appreciate any suggestions. // Thanks

Comment: What operating system and architecture are you programming for?  Is the program a native binary or is it written for some sort of virtual machine?  You have provided no useful details in your question.  This way, it cannot be answered.

Comment: @fuz - I do not have any source code of the program, I can only reverse code it using Assembly / HEX. This is a Windows game.

Comment: Find the `CreateWindowEx` call that creates the window and change the style to include `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`.

Comment: @Jester is there a program that does this, or will I have to use IDA / ollydbg for it?

Comment: Use IDA/olly.  Put a breakpoint on `CreateWindowEx` and see where it's called from.

Comment: @Jester There is no CreateWindowEx function or call that I can find, nor any WS_ call